# Array to Hash in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using ZRANK function in the node_redis module with "WITHSCORES" option and it returns an array in the following format:

**Available**

```
[value1, score1, value2, score2,...,valueN, scoreN].
```

Is there a simple way in NodeJS to convert it into an array of hashes in the following format:

**Required Format**

```
 [{value1 : score1}, {value2 : score2},..., {valueN : scoreN}]
```

I'm not sure if this question is answered before. I couldn't find any.

Comment: What did you try? Nothing? Go try something! Ask a question when such an attempt results in real problems (this helps formulate more directed questions). The 'native JavaScript' way is with a loop; either double-increment each loop or use a modulus/toggle, etc. There are more clever ways with *external* libraries such as lodash.

Comment: Don't even need an external library for this one - you can easily do this with a native higher order function.

Comment: @gabdallah There is no native higher order function in ES5.1 for this: might as well forget the 'higher order function'. (Such requires some notion of `zip` function.)

Comment: map filter and reduce are all higher order functions and are all available on the Array prototype in ES5

Comment: @gabdallah And none of them solve the problem in an simple pure manner (well, reduce is not too bad and can be used - more simply than a loop? That's debatable). But saying 'use xyz here because it's a higher order function' is nonsense by itself: each (vs a simple loop), map, and filter are not well-applicable here and yet they are all 'higher order'.

Comment: the required format is not valid javascript syntax ... do you mean `[{value1: score1},{ ...]` etc

Comment: @user2864740 given that es5 isn't a requirement in this case - here's a pretty easy to comprehend one liner: [value1, score1, value2, score2,...,valueN, scoreN].reduce((arrayToReturn, val, index) => index % 2 === 0 ? [...arrayToReturn, { [val]: test[index+1]}] : arrayToReturn, []); So yes, you can do this natively in the language fairly easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ugly (no longer hackish) it gets the job done

```
var output = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].reduce((result, value, index, array) => {
    if (index % 2) {
        result.push({[array[index - 1]]: value});
    }
    return result;
}, []);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: must be using an old version of IE - this code is standard in Javascript now and works in Chrome/Firefox

Comment: @user2864740 ES6 is the official standard for the language. Node.js is built on the V8 engine. Please read up on object initializers and dynamic keys. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Comment: @user2864740 I'm starting to think you're a troll. Didn't say Node.js is a language - it is built on the V8 engine which is coming into the ES6 standard. ES6 is finalized and standard as of June of last year and you're right it hasn't always supported ES6 - but things evolve http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/

Comment: @JaromandaX I learned something new and removed the no-longer relevant comments. Thanks.

Comment: @user2864740 - I respect you for it - always a good day when one learns at least one thing

Comment: @user2864740 the bat and ball remark was flippant and wasn't meant in any way disrespectful

Answer (score 0):

..or one could write it as so, even using a function for self-documentation; no hack claimed.

```
function flatArrayToPairs (input) {
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i += 2) {
    var item = {};
    item[input[i]] = input[i+1];
    output.push(item);
  }
  return output;
}
```

(The code above doesn't use the ES6 object initializer, due to a lack of updated knowledge on my part; doing so would make it two lines shorter.)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be pretty easy to read while giving you what you want.

```
var arr = ['value1', 'score1', 'value2', 'score2']
  , result = [];

arr.forEach(function(item, index, arr){
  if (index%2 === 0){
    result.push({[item]: arr[index+1]})
  }else{
   return;
  }
});
//will produce:
[
  {
    "value1": "score1"
  },
  {
    "value2": "score2"
  }
]
```

or

```
var result = arr.map((item, index, arr) => ({[item]: arr[index + 1]}))
  .filter((item, index, ) => (index % 2 === 0))
```